# Проблема с байтовыми строками

Tags: python-3.x

Собственно, проблема состоит в следующем. Допустим, есть строка `string='abc'`. От нее требуется получить хэш. Для этого я использую библиотеку `hashlib`. Для использования хэш-функции необходима байтовая строка, например вот так: `sha512(b'abc').hexdigest()`
Но этот способ не работает, если содержимое строки нам неизвестно(например, если оно вводится пользователем). `sha512(b'{}'.format(string))` также не работает, так как байтовые строки нельзя форматировать.
Что может сработать в этом случае? (*я не имею особого опыта в задавании вопросов, поэтому заранее приношу извинения*)

Comment: `sha512(bytes(string, encoding="utf-8"))` / `sha512(bytes(string, "utf-8"))` или через `str.encode`: `sha512(string.encode())` / `sha512(string.encode("utf-8"))`. Если кодировку не указывать, то будет использоваться системная кодировка

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, использовал `string.encode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Спасибо участнику [gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201445/gil9red) за ответ*
Возможны следующие варианты:

`#1 
sha512(bytes(string, encoding="utf-8"))`

`#2
sha512(bytes(string, "utf-8"))`

`#3
sha512(string.encode())`

`#4
sha512(string.encode("utf-8"))`

Если кодировку не указывать, то будет использоваться системная кодировка